# Compiling SBCL on NetBSD as User?

Tags: compilation, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, bsd

I am trying to install SBCL 2.3.1 on a NetBSD server running NetBSD ver. 9.3. I am not root on this system and therefore I am installing to `~/bin/sbcl` within my home folder.

Make seems to proceed fine for some length of time, and does appear to find my local install of ECL (which is in my PATH) since it does seem to initially compile some LISP files followed by C files, but then I seem to run out of memory during the install. It reports the following error:

```
[building initial core file in "output/cold-sbcl.core":
writing 32768 bytes [1 page] from #<SB-FASL::GSPACE @#x20000000 :STATIC>
writing 1835008 bytes [56 pages] from #<SB-FASL::GSPACE @#x20100000 :IMMOBILE-FIXEDOBJ>
writing 14581760 bytes [445 pages] from #<SB-FASL::GSPACE @#x21A00000 :IMMOBILE-TEXT>
writing 23134208 bytes [706 pages] from #<SB-FASL::GSPACE @#x1000000000 :DYNAMIC>
writing 0 bytes [0 pages] from #<SB-FASL::GSPACE @#x20000000 :READ-ONLY>
movable dynamic space: 158 + 0 + 548 cons/code/mixed pages
/INITIAL-FUN=#X22757BEB
done]
//testing for consistency of first and second GENESIS passes
//header files match between first and second GENESIS -- good
      124.23 real       116.92 user         5.58 sys
//entering make-target-2.sh
//doing warm init - compilation phase
mmap: Permission denied
failed to allocate 1048576 bytes at 0x20000000
(hint: Try "ulimit -a"; maybe you should increase memory limits.)
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
```

I did try to limit the memory limit on the compile by using this invocation of gmake, but it still produces the same error:

```
sh make.sh --prefix=/home/my-name/bin/sbcl  --dynamic-space-size=444Mb
```

Comment: I think, as the message says, this is the system's memory limit, not SBCLs: you need to find out what the limits are with `ulimit -a` and then increase them.

Comment: If you're not root, there is probably little chance for you to increase the memory limit.

Comment: @molbdnilo: depends on whether the limit is hard or soft.